# How do I put my custom syntax highlighting in .vimrc?

Tags: c++, c, vim, syntax-highlighting

I use a shorthand form for the basic C/C++ types and I want Vim to syntax highlight them. I added

`syn keyword cType u8 s8 u16 s16 u32 s32 u64 s64 f32 f64 byte`

to my `.vimrc`, but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1** It has been suggested elsewhere that the problem is when Vim loads the syntax files for C or C++ it overrides my custom syntax in .vimrc. Is that the problem?

**UPDATE 2** Duskwuff's answer hinted to me to look at Vim's `runtimepath` variable, which I am setting to a shared network drive, `S:\vim\_vim`, but Vim was still looking for the `after` directory in `~\vimfiles\after`, which didn't exist! I added `S:\vim\_vim\after` to the `runtimepath` variable and it seems to have fixed the problem of the syntax files not loading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to extend the behavior of an existing vim syntax file (e.g, `c.vim`), create the file `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`, and add the extra `syn` command there. It'll be loaded after the main `c.vim` syntax file.

Comment: Not working. The syntax highlight still isn't applied when loading a .c or .cpp file. (I tried naming the file c.vim and cpp.vim - neither worked)

Comment: @DrTwox What does `:echo &ft` say when you edit a C file? Do you have `syntax on` in your .vimrc?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves `:echo &ft` outputs `c` for .c files and `cpp` for .cpp files. Syntax is on and working, just not for my custom syntax.

Comment: Fixed! I had a problem with my `runtimepath` variable that was preventing Vim loading the files. I've updated the question to include what the fix was, and will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: This works for neovim too. Except the path will be `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/c.vim`.